# Fedora 39 - removed bluez & bluez-cups now have no internet access at all

Tags: fedora, wifi, internet, dnf, bluez

I was rushing and not paying attention and used `$dnf remove` instead of `$dnf downgrade` while attempting to downgrade bluez and bluez-cups from 5.70 due to the error connecting certain devices.

After removing those packages and reinstalling the older bluez and bluez-cups, I noticed that I no longer had an ethernet connection, and I couldn’t see any of my WiFi networks.

dnf removed 3 other packages, NetworkManager-bluetooth, and bluedevil and bluez-obexd

I reinstalled the NetworkManager-bluetooth package.
I tried `$dnf history undo` and `$dnf history rollback`

There is no problem with the WiFi or ethernet, they are working fine on Windows on the same machine.

Does anyone have any ideas what might have happened?

**DNF history with offending command**

```
$ sudo dnf history
ID | Command line | Date and time | Action(s) | Altered
27 | install NetworkManager-blueto | 2023-12-04 00:19 | Install        |    1
26 | install bluez-5.68-1.fc38.x86 | 2023-12-03 23:33 | Install        |    2 EE
25 | remove bluez bluez-cups       | 2023-12-03 23:30 | Removed        |    5 EE
```

**Resolve**

```
 $ resolvectl status
    Global
    Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: stub
    
    Link 2 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: none
    Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    
    Link 3 (wlp4s0)
    Current Scopes: none
    Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

**PCI**

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Gold P31/BC711/PC711 NVMe Solid State Drive
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5416 (rev 01)
06:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function (rev c5)
06:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
06:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
06:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
06:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
07:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
07:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

**Network Manager**

```
$systemctl status NetworkManager
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
└─10-timeout-abort.conf
Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-12-04 00:22:46 GMT; 27min ago
Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
Main PID: 1944 (NetworkManager)
Tasks: 4 (limit: 38299)
Memory: 8.1M
CPU: 316ms
CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
└─1944 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```